# listbox not showing all columns from SQL table

Tags: c#, sql

Created a class to return columns from an SQL table [USER]. But when the data shows in the listbox it only shows the first two columns.

Class to return columns

```
public class User
{
    public int USER_ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }



    public string FullInfo
    {
        get {
            return $"{USER_ID} { Username } { First_Name } { Surname } { Email } ";
            }

    }

}
```

Calling the User class and populating the listbox

```
 public partial class DashBoard : Form
{
    List<User> user = new List<User>();
    public DashBoard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UpdateBinding();
    }

    private void UpdateBinding()
    {

        UserFoundListBox.DataSource = user;
        UserFoundListBox.DisplayMember = "FullInfo";
    }

    private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataAccess db = new DataAccess();

        user = db.GetUser(LastNameText.Text);
        UpdateBinding();
    }

}
```

When I add a break point and go into user, I can see that the data returns correctly. But when I look into fullinfo I can only see USER_ID and USERNAME. When I look in the text visualiser for fullinfo I can see that all the columns are returned but with big spaces between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatypes in the fields of my database were nchar(250).

I deleted all data from the [USER] table and updated the fields to varchar(250) and then inserted data. This meant all the spaces were gone and all the data showed.